# Searching multiple fields with multiple queries in Spring Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Elasticsearch. This is my java class :

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "shopindex")
public class Shop implements Serializable {


  private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) Long id;  

  private String imagePath;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "description")
  private String description;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "locality")
  private String locality;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "city")
  private String city;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "state")
  private String state;

  private String timing;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
  private ArrayList<Listing> listings;

  Shop () {}

}
```

I want to have two query strings, location and query. I want query to search through fields name, description, and listing and location to search through fields address, location, city, and state. I am using this query for search but I am getting exception :

```
 NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
          .withQuery(boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(location, "address", "locality", "city", "state"))
          .must(boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, "name", "description"))
          
          .should(QueryBuilders
                  .nestedQuery("listings", 
                          QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, "listings.name", "listings.description"),ScoreMode.Avg))))
          .build();
 Iterable<Shop> itr = searchRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

Comment: how should this be combined? logical _and_? or _or_? What have you tried to search your data?

Comment: Logical and. Updated the question to add what have I tried so far.

Comment: the second call to `withQuery()` replaces the query you set in the first call. You would need to wrap these in a boolQuery to combine them. Or use the `CriteriaQuery` that Spring Data Elasticsearch offers.